# command illegal or legal (Assembley 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
  DSEG SEGMENT 

   A1 DW 12
   A2 DB 2 DUP (12H,34,'2','B')
DSEG ENDS
```

I have this 2 commands

```
1. MOV WORD PTR A2+1[BX+DI],SI
  2. NOT BYTE PTR A1+1[BX+SI][DI]
```

ARE THEY ILLEGAL OR NOT?

Comment: I'd expect your assembler to tell you directly.  Why are you asking us  instead of it? [I think your NOT instruction is syntactically wrong in any case].

Comment: @IraBaxter why it is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

2 is illegal

- **NOT** is a unary instruction, so only takes one operand (it works 'in place')
- even if it was binary, you have mismatched operand sizes -- **BYTE PTR** is a byte (8 bit) operand, while **DI** is a word (16-bit) register operand.

regardless, the instructions don't make a lot of sense.  What are you trying to do?

With the update, the second instruction has illegal syntax.  It appears that you *might* be trying to use three registers for an address computation, but there's no way to do that -- an address can refer to a single base register (BP or BX) plus a single index register (DI or SI) plus an optional displacement (a constant address).